# Using Intervention package to compress images. My images are not being compressed, still the same size

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I'm using this package http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation to compress my images that's uploaded to my server. However the images are not being compressed.

1. First I installed the Intervention package by putting this in my 
   terminal:

   > composer require intervention/image
2. Then I added this at the top of my controller:

   > use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
3. Then I added the encode to minify the image

   > Image::make(request()->file('img'))->encode('jpg', 1);
4. It's not minifying the image. It's still the same size.

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   class UploadsController extends Controller
   {

       public function store()
       {

           // Get image
           $img = request()->file('img');

           // Minify image
           Image::make($img)->encode('jpg', 1);

           // Store image in uploads folder
           Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads', $img);

       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

> Quality is only applied if you're encoding JPG format since PNG compression is lossless and does not affect image quality. Default: 90.

Use `jpg` if you want this library to compress your images.

Comment: Is the original image a PNG?

Comment: No, it's a jpg.

Comment: Did you just rename the image as a .jpg? because that wouldn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are just saving the original image and not the resized version. You could try something like this:

```
public function store()
{

    // Get image
    $img = request()->file('img');

    // Minify image
    $resizedImage = Image::make($img)->encode('jpg', 1); // put this in a variable

   // use a unique filename
   $filename = $img->hashName()

    // Store image in uploads folder
    Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads/'.$filename, $resizedImage->__toString());

}
```