# Laravel 5.1 Intervention Image compressing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I use Laravel 5.1 and the intervention package:
http://image.intervention.io/

I try to compress my images. I would like to upload a 2.5Mb image and compress it by reducing the image size to arround 700kb by keeping the resolution and the image quality. Just reducing a large image file to a small one.
The uploaded image is a .jpg file

I use the following code:

```
$targetFolder = public_path().'/images/';
$name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
$extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); // add
$picture = sha1($name . time()) . '.' . $extension; //add

$image->move($targetFolder, $picture);
$image = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make(sprintf('images/%s', $picture))->encode('jpg', 75);
```

But my image size is still arround 2.07Mb

The question is what method I have to use to get the desired result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Intervention package to compress images. My images are not being compressed, still the same size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432345/using-intervention-package-to-compress-images-my-images-are-not-being-compresse)

Comment: My image is a .jpg file

Comment: It looks like you are moving the image before you encode it.

Comment: how it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

you have compress or reducing the image size it will better work for you and it will also work for me that gives a best resolution after image is compressed

```
$path = public_path().'/public_thumb_photo/';

        File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);

        $extension=$request->file('thumb')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $filename=$request->file('thumb')->getClientOriginalName();

        $imgname ='public_thumb_photo_'.mt_rand(000000,999999) . '.'.$extension;

        $request->file('thumb')->move($path,$imgname);

        $data = getimagesize($path.$imgname);
                    $widths = $data[0];
                    $heights = $data[1];

                     if($widths > 1000 && $heights > 1000)
                    {
                        //dd("demo1");
                        if($widths > 3000 && $heights > 3000)
                        {
                            //dd("demo123");
                            $width = $widths - 1000;    
                            $height = $heights - 1000;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //dd("demo 2");
                            $width = $widths - 500;
                            $height = $heights - 500;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //dd("demo 3");
                        $width = $widths - 250;
                        $height = $heights - 250;
                    }


                    Image::make($path.$imgname)->resize($width,$height,function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    })->save($path.$imgname,20);
```